# Why is “qaautomation.net” missing from the Firefox Page Source?

Tags: java, html, selenium, firefox

For the example program on the webpage

http://www.qaautomation.net/?p=263

I carry out the following steps:

1. Run the program with the driver.close() line of code commented out.
2. The program opens a Firefox browser, then searches for the term "qa automation" on google.
3. Once the "Test passed." message has been printed to the screen (in the console), go to the google search results page.
4. Using the browser menu, go to Tools/Web Developer/Page Source.
5. On the page source page, search for the term "qaautomation.net".
6. Quit the Firefox application.
7. Open Firefox and a browser window manually i.e. not using the program.
8. Go to google.com and search manually for "qa automation".
9. When the results page has loaded, carry out Steps 4 and 5 above.

I get no search results in Step 5 but I do in Step 9. Why is this? Both page sources appear to derive from the same webpage. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: I know you are trying to clarify your original question but in the future, it's OK to just edit your original question for clarification. I would remove your original question or this one will likely get dup'd to the first because they are pretty much the same question.

Comment: btw... when I do this manually, I get just the CSS and JS, etc. and no actual content on the page. Some google searches are showing that this is an issue for some users. Is there some reason you are searching the source instead of just scraping the page for the content? I'll post an alternative search approach, if you are interested.

Comment: Thanks for your time in responding. I looked into deleting my original question, but it seems that the website doesn't like it as there's already an answer. As for your other comments, I'm fairly new with HTML, CSS, JS etc. I am learning about web automation, which brought me to the program that I referenced. Basically, my query comes down to: when I run the program, "qaautomation.net" can't be found in the Page Source; however, when I carry out the program's steps manually, I CAN find "qaautomation.net" in the Page Source, and I would like to know why..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of searching through the HTML source, I would suggest that you just scrape the page. This method will let you more specifically target where you are seeing the text... in a link href vs text on the page vs ???, etc.

The code below demonstrates two different places that you can look for the "qaautomation.net" text. The first is in the heading link href and the second is in the citation link that occurs immediately below the heading href.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("qa automation\n"); // need the \n to simulate hitting ENTER to start the search
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains("Google Search")); // need to wait until the results page loads
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("h3.r > a"));
// System.out.println("links: " + links.size()); // for debugging
for (WebElement link : links)
{
    // looking for qaautomation.net in the link href
    if (link.getAttribute("href").contains("qaautomation.net"))
    {
        System.out.println("PASS: found in href");
    }
}
List<WebElement> cites = driver.findElements(By.tagName("cite"));
// System.out.println("cites: " + cites.size()); // for debugging
for (WebElement cite : cites)
{
    // looking for qaautomation.net in the citation (text below the heading link)
    if (cite.getText().contains("qaautomation.net"))
    {
        System.out.println("PASS: found in cite");
    }
}

System.out.println("DONE");
```